# Weird response with enumerate and dict in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, enumerate

Using the `dict(enumerate(x))`, we get the `{ (index, value) }`. Instead, I need `{ (value, index) }`.
So, I've written this code...

```
idx= { n:i for i, n in enumerate(x)}
```

It works with some inputs and fails with others.
Here's an input where it is failing.

```
x= [73,74,75,71,69,72,76,73]
```

, Why is it failing? and what should be done?

Comment: What do you mean by *failing*? what did you get and how is it different from what you expected?

Comment: You have repeating values in your list. The list is going to be keys. dict keys are unique.

Comment: `{(value, index)}` looks like a `set` of `tuple`s, not a dictionary. Which one are you looking for?

Comment: ` {73: 7, 74: 1, 75: 2, 71: 3, 69: 4, 72: 5, 76: 6} ` is what it shows when I print idx. By reading the comments realised that the ambiguity rises as 73 occurred multiple times. How to avoid this? @Guy                   [idx is a dictionary of tuples]

Comment: Are you looking for the values in the `idx` dictionaries to be lists by chance? or are you expecting the value if `idx[73]` to be `0` not `7` despite the second `73`?

Comment: What result do you hope to get with that input? What result do you hope to get if `x = [1, 1, 2]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Why is it failing?**

We know that for:

```
x = [73,74,75,71,69,72,76,73, 99]  # note the additional list item
```

The result:

```
{73: 7, 74: 1, 75: 2, 71: 3, 69: 4, 72: 5, 76: 6, 99: 8}
```

is *"bad"* for at least the first key in the dictionary. The reason it is bad (as others have pointed out) is that there are duplicate entries in the list `x` and as we process them we are conceptually doing:

```
idx = {}
idx[73] = 0
idx[73] = 7
print(idx)
```

> **What should be done?**

We don't know what you actually expect for the key of `73`. I think there is a good chance you want the value `0` but perhaps you want the value `[0, 7]` showing both indexes of `73` in the original list.

The other wrinkle is not knowing how the additional item `99` (occurring after the duplicated `73`) should be assigned a value. Do we keep the existing index entry `8` or do we want that to be a new `7` effectively replacing the duplicate?

Determining how to get some other result is fairly straight forward and I'll give you several things you can try.

**Option 1:**

I want the keys to have their actual first list indexes:

```
73 --> 0
99 --> 8
```

```py
idx_expected = {73: 0, 74: 1, 75: 2, 71: 3, 69: 4, 72: 5, 76: 6, 99: 8}
idx_actual = {}
for index, value in enumerate(x):
    if value not in idx_actual:
        idx_actual[value] = index
print(idx_actual == idx_expected)
```

**Option 2:**

I want the keys to have their first list indexes but if there is a duplicate, I just want to pretend it did not exist:

```
73 --> 0
99 --> 7
```

```py
## -------------
idx_expected = {73: 0, 74: 1, 75: 2, 71: 3, 69: 4, 72: 5, 76: 6, 99: 7}
idx_actual = {n:i for i, n in enumerate(dict.fromkeys(x))}
print(idx_actual == idx_expected)
## -------------
```

**Option 3:**

I want to capture the fact that there could be duplicates in the original list by setting the values in the resulting dictionary to a list of original indexes.

```
73 --> [0, 7]
99 --> [8]
```

```py
## -------------
idx_expected = {73: [0, 7], 74: [1], 75: [2], 71: [3], 69: [4], 72: [5], 76: [6], 99: [8]}
idx_actual = {}
for index, value in enumerate(x):
    idx_actual.setdefault(value, []).append(index)
print(idx_actual == idx_expected)
## -------------
```

Answer (score 1):

`73` is contained twice in vector `x= [73,74,75,71,69,72,76,73]`, which results in ambiguity (the same key corresponds to two different index values.)

Comment: This is indeed why OP is not getting the expected behaviour. However, the actual behaviour is not ambiguous, it's deterministic: the last value written for each key is the one that survives, so the result always contains `73: 7` and never `73: 0`.